# Flex Datagrid Selection

Tags: flash, datagrid, flex4, air

I have a dataGrid in Flex to which data is added dynamically using

```
dataGrid1.dataProvider=myArrayCollection;
```

The DataGrid is non-editable and defined in mxml as

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dataGrid1" selectable="true">
    <!--columns go in here, removed for stackoverflow post -->
</mx:DataGrid>
```

The data in myArrayCollection definitely does not contain duplicates.

My problem: I am not able to select any row except the last.

This occurs when I overlay the AIR 3 SDK on my copy of Flex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the code breaks when the objects in the arrayCollection are complex objects. I have posted a bug report on Adobe's site [here](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-31862). The workaround: make a simple wrapper class with only 1 property: the actual object. This will make the selection work again, though you will have quite some reworking of code to do